# How to use Webpacks 'require' and 'require.ensure' in TypesScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sass, webpack

I am trying to integrate TypeScript into Webpack and am looking for some @types that will help with all the Webpack specific stuff.

I was using `declare function require(string): any;` to use fe.: `require('some.scss')` but quickly got annoyed with adding it directly or over the `/// <reference path="...` syntax and was hoping that there is a better way to do this.

The ideal thing would be just `npm i @types/webpack` but that package only seems to be for the Webpack config file which I think is totally useless...

to be more specific, I am trying to get this code to work in TypeScript:

```
require.ensure([
    require('./first')
], function(require) {
    require('./second')
}, 'second');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are available in [@types/webpack-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webpack-env)

```
npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-env
```